# Is there a way to use my European (PAL) XBox 360 on an NTSC TV?

Tags: xbox-360

After bringing my European (Irish) XBox 360 to the US, I've found that my TV doesn't support PAL (except in black and white with PAL-60). Is there a way to make my XBox 360 output NTSC (such as by modding it, for example)? Alternatively, do converters exist to make this work?

Comment: I know it says Xbox, but just to be sure: The Xbox 1, not the 360?

Comment: What sort of connection are you using between the Xbox and your television?

Comment: Aubergine: the yellow cable (I think it's called "composite")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a converter to change the signal from PAL to NTSC. a cheap simple converter such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RJV2HE) will do the job if all you have are composite outputs. converters do exist for higher definition output (component, HDMI etc)  but expect to pay more.